# How to tell if you're in a git-svn repo command line?

Tags: git, svn, bash, git-svn

I'm trying to modify my bash prompt to print out if I'm in a git-svn repo. I see that git svn repos have a .git/svn folder, so I could check with:

```
# Find the top level git folder
_git_dir=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null`
# Find svn folder
_gsvn_check=`cd $_git_dir; ls .git/svn 2> /dev/null`
```

But then I noticed that my normal git repo has a .git/svn folder. Is there any way to know for sure that you're in git-svn?

Comment: can you post your solution please?

Comment: yes, I'd be interested in your solution as well.  I've been searching for a theme that does this, but haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.git/svn` directory can be created if you run any `git svn` command in any repository - e.g. just running `git svn info`, as [Carl Norum suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085625/223092) will create it.  However, a slightly better test might be that `.git/svn` exists and is non-empty, e.g.

```
[ -d .git/svn  ] && [ x != x"$(ls -A .git/svn/)" ] && echo Looks like git-svn
```

If you want a stricter test, you could look through the history of `HEAD` for any commit messages that contain a `git-svn-id` - essentially that's what `git svn info` is doing before it gives up.  For example:

```
[ x != x"$(git log -n 1 --grep='^\s*git-svn-id' --oneline)" ] && echo "git-svn!"
```

... but it sounds as if that might be too slow for your use case.

The source code in `git-svn.perl` describes the layout of a `git-svn` repository in its different versions:

- https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-svn.perl#L6433

... so you could write tests for all of those if you want to be careful to catch all the different versions.

Comment: Good idea. Also, I found the .git/svn/.metadata file which is only in my git-svn repo and not my git repo where I ran git svn info, so I might use that for the check.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `git svn info`.  Example output for a git-svn repository:

```
Path: .
URL: svn+ssh://url/path/to/something/trunk
Repository Root: svn+ssh://path/to/something
Repository UUID: c22683c8-8Bcb-47f9-aeb8-1c337d8f7a2d
Revision: 12345
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: somebody
Last Changed Rev: 12345
Last Changed Date: 2012-01-24 16:38:36 -0800 (Tue, 24 Jan 2012)
```

And for a regular git repo:

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

Comment: git svn info is super slow, something i'd prefer not to run every time I display my prompt. I wonder how git svn info knows...

Comment: just if I'm in a git svn repo, that's all, I just need a boolean